# Change operating system Regional Settings programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, windows-ce

We use a Windows CE 6.0 device where the locale is set to "English (United Kingdom". This locale uses the point (.) as the `Decimal symbol` (decimal) and the comma (,) as the `Digit grouping symbol` (group).

Normally the customer neither fiddles with nor even sees Operating System settings since only our application is running. However, recently a customer managed to exit our application to the Windows CE desktop and then changed the locale to "German (Germany)".

[image: Locale set to Germany]

The German locale swaps the decimal and group symbols. This has resulted in previously stored registry or XML values such as "7.724" being read in as "7724"! Is there any simple way to deal with this?

Some ideas that suggest themselves are:

- Force the system locale back to "English (United Kingdom)"
- Update the registry so that decimal and group symbols are point and comma respectively (regardless of other locale settings)
- For all decimal values: First convert to a string, replace any group symbols found with the current system decimal separator, then only convert to a single
- Update all `Convert.ToXXX(Object)` calls to use `Convert.ToXXX(Object, IFormatProvider)`

Comment: Why (or, more importantly: what) are you asking us?

Comment: The first two are user-hostile, the third one seems brittle, so I'd go with the last one, even though it's probably the most work.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Err, thought it was clear. My code expects the locale to be `English (United Kingdom)` and in 99.99% of cases that is correct. But this customer has discovered the locale setting and decided to change it. Is there general advice for dealing with this situation...

Comment: @stuartd: Yes, I'm coming to that conclusion as well. But as you point out, this incurs a significant amount of work. This application is legacy (though with tens of thousands in the wild) and supposed to be in maintenance mode only...my manager is not going to like the answer but it does seem the most reasonable.

Comment: Well that's my point exactly. All solutions you mention are potential solutions, the one you want to apply has to be chosen by you, you are the only one who can evaluate all the pros and cons and choose the most viable for this situation. Yes, forcing the locale back to en-UK is "user-hostile", but if the devices are handed out by your company and/or only used for your application, what's the harm?

Comment: @CodeCaster: True, these devices are supposed to be locked down and are single-purpose devices. Forcing them to use the "en-GB" locale is definitely one of the options we will consider.